# autolayout's visual format does not work with iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have a simple `ViewController` that contains only its default view with a background image placed on it, I have the following `updateViewConstraints` method which works perfectly on `iOS 7` devices (without any call to setNeedsXXX methods):

```
    -(void) updateViewConstraints {

[super updateViewConstraints];

[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"bgImage":self.bgImageView};

NSArray * constraints;
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bgImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[bgImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
[[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

}
```

however, this method does not work as expected on `iOS 8` devices, the background image is shifted up and didn't fit in place.

any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];` removes more on iOS 8 than on iOS 7. The easies way to fix this it to add an array holding the constraints you add to the view and remove only those constraints.

Maybe you even can remove this line completely but this depends on your application.

Comment: but I still want to remove the default constraints that comes from storyboard, how can I remove them ?

Comment: Try to set `translatesAutorezisingMasksToContraints` to `NO`. And check via NSLog if there are unexpected constraints. If so, add constraints in the storyboard and check the check box `Remove at build` or something like that.